# Azure IoT Edge Module fails to authenticate

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have a few modules written in node.js using VSC scaffolding. They fail to connect as below:
[UnauthorizedError: mqtt.js returned Failure on first connection (Not authorized): connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:8883 error] {
transportError: Error: Failure on first connection (Not authorized): connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:8883
at /app/node_modules/azure-iot-device-mqtt/dist/mqtt.js:237:104
at constructor._onEnter (/app/node_modules/azure-iot-mqtt-base/dist/mqtt_base.js:209:29)
at constructor.transition (/app/node_modules/machina/lib/machina.js:653:28)
at constructor.Fsm. [as transition] (/app/node_modules/machina/lib/machina.js:466:63)
at /app/node_modules/azure-iot-mqtt-base/dist/mqtt_base.js:288:40
at /app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:827:11
at Store.close (/app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js:124:5)
at /app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:821:26
at Store.close (/app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/store.js:124:5)
at MqttClient.closeStores (/app/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:820:24)
}
/app/app.js:20

It goes on forever. The device is connected via MQTTSoWS, which is the only special thing about this devices, since the same module works well on another edge device connected over MQTTS.

Comment: Eventually the error changes into
```
[UnauthorizedError: mqtt.js returned Failure on first connection (Not authorized): getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN rfidpoc error] {
  transportError: Error: Failure on first connection (Not authorized): getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN rfidpoc
```

Comment: This needs more information from logs. Can you open an issue using the [Bug Report Template](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=) in IoT Edge Github Repo?

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue there. Here it is for reference: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/6049